# array_rand why will get 0 in range(1, 20)

Tags: php

Why is 0 returned from `array_rand()`? How can I filter out 0? I just want to get 1-20.

```
$range = range(1, 20); 
$total = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    shuffle($range);
    array_push($total, array_rand($range, 3));
}
```

Comment: I ensure I got 0 so I don't know why will get 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_rand()` returns the key(s) from the array, and `range()` built an array with a starting key of `0`.  Try:

```
$range = array_combine($range = range(1, 20), $range);
```

Or to treat the keys as the values and not use the actual values:

```
$range = array_flip(range(1, 20));
```

However, you have already shuffled the array so no need for `array_rand()`, just slice 3 from the beginning:

```
$range = range(1, 20); 

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    shuffle($range);
    $total[] = array_slice($range, 0, 3);
}
```